# Prisma ORM e SqlServer: não consigo conectar ao banco de dados mesmo usando o "trustServerCertificate=true"

Tags: node.js, api, linux, prisma

[PRINTSCREEN DO ERRO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8ser.jpg)

Tenho servidor local rodando **Ubuntu Server**, onde fica hospedada minha API **construída em NodeJS e Prisma ORM** e o banco de dados **SQL Server** está hospedado em outro servidor local que roda **Windows Server 2019**.

Quando estou desenvolvendo na minha maquina local que roda **Windows 11 PRO**, o Prisma ORM consegue conectar rapidamente e consegue mapear todo o banco de dados sem nenhum erro.

Porém quando tento mapear o banco de dados no servidor Linux **(npx prisma db pull)** recebo o erro:

> Error: P1011

> Error opening a TLS connection: The TLS settings didn't allow the connection to be established. Please review your connection string. (error: unexpected EOF)

Algumas pessoa afirmaram que era só adicionar o  **"trustServerCertificate=true"** no **"DatabaseURL"** porém continuo recebendo o mesmo erro:

> Error: P1011
>
> Error opening a TLS connection: The TLS settings didn't allow the connection to be established. Please review your connection string. (error: unexpected EOF)

---

Dei um **ping** e o servidor LINUX consegue ver o servidor WINDOWS

[PING LINUX-WINDOWS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2fd6.png)

---

`ARQUIVO .env`

```
PORT=3001

DATABASE_URL="sqlserver://MY_IP:1433;user=MY_USER;password=MY_PASS;TrustServerCertificate=true;database=MY_DB"
```

---

``` ARQUIVO ``schema.prisma ```

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "sqlserver"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Tenta seguir a ordem que esta na documentação, que no caso seria assim:

DATABASE_URL="sqlserver://MY_IP:1433;database=MY_DB;user=MY_USER;password=MY_PASS;trustServerCertificate=true"

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).